# Unzip a MacOS .app file in Electron using Node.js

Tags: node.js, electron, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file called `Restart.Manager.zip` which contains a single item, `Restart Manager.app`. This code seems to unzip the file correctly but upon launching the outputted .app folder, I get an error "The application “Restart Manager” can’t be opened."

```js
const JSZip = require('jszip');
const fs = require('fs');
const jetpack = require('fs-jetpack');
const originalFs = require('original-fs');

async function extractZip(filePath, destination) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      var zip = new JSZip();
      zip.loadAsync(data).then(function(contents) {
        Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(function(filename) {
          const file = zip.file(filename);
          if (file) {
            file.async('nodebuffer').then(function(content) {
              var dest = destination + '/' + filename;
              if (filename.endsWith('.asar')) {
                originalFs.writeFileSync(dest, content)
              } else {
                jetpack.write(dest, content);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
};

extractZip('/Users/me/Desktop/Restart.Manager.zip', '/Users/me/Desktop')
```

Manually unzipping the .zip file creates a working .app so I'm not sure where the code is messing up.

Here is the file on GitHub releases for testing: https://github.com/itw-creative-works/restart-manager-download-server/releases/download/installer/Restart.Manager.zip but feel free to use your own zipped .app file (although it should probably be an Electron app in which case you can find one here https://www.electronjs.org/apps)

I have tried zipping things like a .png and it unzips fine, which makes me think it is having problems with .app files or possibly the fact that the .app contains a .asar file which Electron supposedly has problems handling when it comes to the `fs` module: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1658

Comment: Given that no one in their right mind would run an untrusted .app on a real machine, even if it _did_ work: what happens with normal, "safe" data, first? E.g. does a `.jpg` image work? Also, don't trust things to "seem" correctly unpacked: run `md5` on the content, then compare the md5 print for what you get after unpacking: are they the same? If not: the unpacking did not yield the same data as went in.

Comment: I provided my file as an example. Feel free to zip any .app file and try the code.

Comment: I'm sure, but the implicit request was for _you_ to add that information to your post, because that's important debugging information that tell others what you've already checked, and this what can already be ruled out (or not). So: please check what happens for some common (but byte-corruption-sensitive) file types like JPG, put that in your post, and also report what you see happening in terms of byte digests (be that crc32, md5, sha1, it doesn't really matter as long as it's a stable hash) before archiving, and after unpacking.

Comment: I have tested it with a simple .png image and it works as expected. I have updated the question to reflect these findings as well as some more research on how Electron handles .asar files with the `fs` module.